# how can i use googlemap gRPC in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, grpc

I would like to use routeAPI - gRPC on Android.
But in none of the documents, I can't find how to define the message in the proto file.

What I looked for as much as I could is this document.

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/reference/rpc/google.maps.routing.v2?hl=ko#computeroutesrequest

Is there a way for me to implement route API pathfind on android with gRPC?
or
googleMap gRPC android Example?

Thank you.

I want to use gRPC in android

Comment: What is gRPC. ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer your question literally (I'm not familiar with the Maps API and so unable to comment on other ways that this may be done).

Google publishes all (most!?) of its gRPC services in a public GitHub repo called [`googleapis`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/).

Google's gRPCs are namespaced `google` and are then namespaced by service e.g. `maps` and, in your case `google/maps/routing/v2` contains multiple protos but the one of primary interest is [`routes_service.proto`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/maps/routing/v2/routes_service.proto) and specifically line 87 which defines [`ComputeRoutes`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/maps/routing/v2/routes_service.proto#L87) which, I think is what you're after!?

```protobuf
rpc ComputeRoutes(ComputeRoutesRequest) returns (ComputeRoutesResponse)
```

Now (!) generally (!?) Google publishes SDKs that implement the gRPC stubs for these services. Please ensure that the SDK doesn't already exist as it will save you time.

However, because gRPC defines the services (`rpc`'s and `method`'s), we can generate the stubs for ourselves:

If you clone `googleapis`, the protocol buffer `proto_path` (import path) should be this repo's root folder and you can generate the services in `routes_service.proto` using the fully-qualified path `google/maps/routing/v2/routes_service.proto`

`routes_service.proto` has a slew of imports but these are a combination of:

- other references in `googleapis`;
- Google's well-known types (which should be automatically supported).

Comment: That is indeed the right gRPC library. There are also Client libraries for Routes API that should make this easier: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/routes/client-libraries